# LINQ Query using 'StartsWith' with an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

In My LINQ Query I use Where Clauses to check whether a property exists within an array of values. I would like to update the query:

```
string[] itemColour
string[] itemType

List<displayItem> displayItems = (from item in allItems
                                  Where itemColour.Contains(item.colour)
                                  Where itemType.Contains(item.type)
                                  select new displayItem
                                  ......................etc...etc
```

**So what I have is**

'Where my 'itemColour' array contains this 'item.colour' select it'

'Where my 'itemType' array contains this 'item.type' select it'

**What I'm after is**

'Where my 'itemColour' array has an item that has 'item.colour' anywhere in it select it
'Where my 'itemType' array has an item that begins with 'item.type' select it

I'm aware of 'StartsWith' and 'EndsWith' but don't know how to use them with these arrays.

**note:** itemColour may contain an item that has the colour code 'RGW' I would want to be able to select this item based on any of the three letters

**Update**

The suggested solution :

```
var query = from item in allItems
        where itemColour.Any(c => c.Contains(item.colour))
           && itemType.Any(t => t.StartsWith(item.type)
        select ...;
```

has an issue. If I'm trying to bring back an item with the colour Code 'RB'. 
My Array may contain two items 'R' and 'B' the suggested query is only returning items with colour code either 'R' or 'B' not both.

I am using MVC 5, LINQ TO Entity, .NET 4.5

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which allows you to check whether any item in a sequence (the arrays in this case) matches a predicate:

```
var query = from item in allItems
            where itemColour.Any(c => c.Contains(item.colour))
               && itemType.Any(t => t.StartsWith(item.type)
            select ...;
```

There are potential optimizations depending on how many colour entries you have and the exact semantics.

If you want to find items which match *either* colour *or* type, use `||` instead:

```
var query = from item in allItems
            where itemColour.Any(c => c.Contains(item.colour))
               || itemType.Any(t => t.StartsWith(item.type)
            select ...;
```

EDIT: Your description isn't clear, but it's entirely possible that you really want:

```
 itemColour.Any(c => item.colour.Contains(c))
```

instead. Think logically about what you want to check, and apply it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Any was what I needed. but this query isn't producing the results I expected. I'll Edit My Question

Comment: @user2390419: Well without any more information than that, we can't help you. Did you perhaps want `||` instead of `&&`? (In other words, are you trying to find items which match *either* requirement instead of *both*?)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help I've updated my question, my problem is contains doesn't seem to be working the same as 'like'

Comment: @user2390419: Yes it does, but I *suspect* we've got the use of it backwards, based on your original description, which suggested that the `itemColour` array had a value "RGW" and the item would have "R", "G" or "W". I suspect you actually meant it the other way round. It would be easier to help you if you showed sample data or ideally a short but complete program.

Comment: ah you are right I have written that the wrong way round in my question , I have just tested and this is working thanks

Comment: Hi i want to search in table that containing the list of numbers i.e, 0001-1234-5678-9001, 
Now How can i achieve it in wild card with and without dashes in search using linq query?

Comment: @cracker: I suggest you ask a new question with more details (including whether this "table" is in memory, or in SQL etc, and what you mean by "with and without dashes").

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
from item in allItems
where itemColour.Any(x => x.Contains(item.colour))
where itemType.Any(x => x.StartsWith(item.type))
select new displayItem
```